# libwebsockets (on ubuntu) - trying compile example "lws minimal ws server + permessage-deflate echo" - can't find libwebsocketsConfig.cmake

Tags: cmake

I am an (absolute) beginner with libwebsockets (and cmake), and am trying to build one of the minimal examples from libwebsockets.org:

```
"lws minimal ws server + permessage-deflate echo"
```

at

https://libwebsockets.org/git/libwebsockets/tree/minimal-examples/ws-server/minimal-ws-server-echo

I have installed libwebsockets-dev (sudo apt install libwebsockets-dev) and cmake (sudo apt install cmake).

The example page tells me to build the example (two .c files and CMakeLists.txt) using

```
 $ cmake . && make
```

The build fails with the following message:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "libwebsockets"
  with any of the following names:

    libwebsocketsConfig.cmake
    libwebsockets-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "libwebsockets" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "libwebsockets_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "libwebsockets" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it
  has been installed.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/user/ws/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

I cannot find either of the .cmake files in my system (they are evidently not provided as part of package libwebsockets-dev.)

What am I missing?

Thank you!

Comment: As the examples are part of libwebsocket repository, they probably expect you to install the library from that repo, not from the distro packages. Installed from the repo the library should provide `libwebsockets-config.cmake` file. As their `CMakeLists.txt` [uses](https://libwebsockets.org/git/libwebsockets/tree/CMakeLists.txt#n916) `export()` command, it is probably sufficient to just build the library without installation.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, Tsyvarev, you are correct.

The solution was to build libwebsockets from github repository, use that instead of libwebsocket-dev installed from ubuntu 18.04.